# NodeJS and ExpressJS Router.use() error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object at Function. (C:/Users/peter/Desktop/mean/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
```

I was testing my Api in post man and I got this error.

I got it when i in my app.js when I did app.use('/api',api);

app.js:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var session = require("express-session");



var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var api = require('./routes/jokesApi');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');





app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


  app.use(session({secret:'secret_3162735',saveUninitialized:true,     resave: true}));



 // The error comes from here 
 app.use('/api',api);

 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 var session = req.session;
 var input = req.body;

 if(session.userName){
return next();
}else if(input.userName){
session.userName = input.userName;
return res.redirect('/');
}else{
req.url='/login';
return next();
 }

});

app.use('/', routes);
 app.use('/users', users);


 module.exports = app;
```

JokesApi.js:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var jokes = require('../model/jokes');
 var session = require("express-session")
 var router = express.Router();

 router.get('/joke/random',function(req,res,next){
 res.end({joke: jokes.getRandomJoke()});

 });

 router.get('/jokes',function(req,res,next){
 res.end({joke: jokes.allJokes});

 });

router.post('/joke', function(req,res){
var funJoke = req.body;
var jsonJoke = funJoke.Joke;
jokes.addJoke(jsonJoke);
res.end({funnyNewJoke: jsonJoke});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not exporting your router in `jokesApi.js`. Add this to the end of that file:

```
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:524:11)
    at writeend (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\Mean/express-server \untitled\nod
e_modules\express-session\index.js:223:22)

Comment: Change your lines where you're passing an object to `res.end()` to instead use `res.json()`.

Comment: ahh ok now it works. Could you explain why my code with res.end() didnt work?

Comment: `res.write()`/`res.end()` are for writing strings and/or Buffers. `res.json()` is a helper method provided by Express to automatically call `JSON.stringify()` and set the appropriate response headers (e.g. `Content-Type: application/json`).

Answer (score 1):

The module jokesApi needs to be exported:

```
module.exports = router;
```

Try to follow this example: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html